# Vuetify: how to modify the step's default color?

Tags: javascript, css, vuetify.js

I am using the Vuetify's [`Stepper`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers)  component.

By default, the step's color is blue:

[image]

Corresponding piece of code is:

```
<v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="1">Name of step 1</v-stepper-step>
```

Live test on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/begueradj/pen/GXPKVQ?&editors=101).

Comment: Have you used a custom theme ?

Comment: No, I am not using a custom theme, all is set to the default theme @laruiss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply pass a color to `color` attribute  on `v-stepper-step` component.

```
<v-stepper-step color="red">Step 1</v-stepper-step>
```

Custom theme colors e.g. `color="success"` will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the default color with CSS. The element is `v-stepper__step__step` **.primary** :

```
.v-stepper__step__step.primary {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvote your answer, but I will wait for an other approach to decide which one is cleaner. Thank you for the feedback